# xmlhttprequest phonegap not working using the url

Tags: php, android, mysql, ajax, xml

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://moonrays00.comli.com/getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I can't get this to work I am planning to get this project to work for Android

the project was based on

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: try opening `http://moonrays00.comli.com/getuser.php?q=yourtext` in your browser. what is the result?

Comment: @vusan opens up the table only i wanted it be like http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

based on http://moonrays00.comli.com/getuser.php link

Comment: Can you expand on 'I can't get this to work'? What is not working? Have you checked your browser console to see if your ajax executes? Have you verified that something was returned from the your url?

Comment: used xampp i was trying to connect my index.html to the php but it will not let it connect @Sean

Comment: using xampp and local host it worked but i wanted the php to be hosted

Comment: I'm having a related problem, my PHP request works fine using my laptop and localhost on my browser. But when I try it on my Android using phonegap simulator it doesn't show thee content inside my 'txtHint' element using document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;